# Find all branches with having a specific file on their HEAD commits

Tags: git

Task:

- I need to find all branches that have a file by a given name in their HEAD commit.

Situation:

- I can safely assume, there are many (millions of) branches.
- I can also safely assume, there are many files within each branches top dir. This one, I could get down by creating sub dirs, but enforcing this on users would be non-trivial, especially because I want to allow for edits to be made off-line and then have those `git-push`'ed to the server.

Background:

- I'm going to use git repositories for a special wiki project, where each user maintains his own view of the wiki at all times.
- I'm reimplementing the necessary git functions for read only git access in PHP, so giving any git command would be of limited use to me.
- Every user is maintained by one or more branches, there shall be easy access to all other users and branches on each wiki page, where different versions of the same page reside.
- I have only bare repositories on the server.

Currently, my plan is something like this (PHP-ish pseudocode):

```
retval = array();
foreach get_branch() as branch
    if (branch->get_tree()->lookup(name)) {
        retval[] += branch->get_name();
    }
}
```

Obviously, this are two big nested loops, with hundreds of thousands of files and millions of branches, this is nothing I would want to do on every single page access.

So, besides of this, the only option I see is to create my own cache of this information, that I'll update in my post-receive and/or post-commit hooks.

Question:

- Is there any more elegant solution than the ones I described here and which one would that be?

Comment: Using git to maintain even thousands, let alone millions of branches is very outside the work it's designed for.  Use a database, they're made for this.

Comment: So, you're suggesting to store the branches in DB instead of git (problem: git gc would delete just about everything)? Or are you suggesting to just put everything in DB? My point in using git is that there already are tools to manage those. Using a DB would completely render the decentralized aspect of my project non-existing, and there exist enough centralized wikis out there already, no need to code just another one. Oh, and, BTW: There is no need for me to keep git on the server vanilla git. I could perfectly do changes there. It would just need to remain 100% compatible to vannila client.

Comment: Tools to manage what?  There's no way git's going to manage a the numbers of branches you're talking about in a single repo, nor will it  tell you what files are in some other repo's commits.  You do have complete control over when and how gc operates, so there's that anyway.

Comment: the user's repos will only contain a reasonable number of branches, but the main repo which will be accessed by the web application will have ALL branches (as remote brances).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in wiki all pages are in same directory, and searching for specific file would really be linear.

If you somehow manage to store tree objects uncompressed (afaik it is possible only for blobs) then you would be able to locate a file there by binary search. So you could be able to get rid of the inner loop. But seem like there is no way to avoid looping over branches.

Comment: 1) The "all wiki pages are in same directory" is something I have under control. There is nothing preventing me to store a page named "Supercoolpage" under path "Su/pe/rc/oo/lpage".
2) Also, git compresses all four object types, blobs, commits, tags and trees. And it also uses delta encoding on all of those types (but only within one type, so from tree 1 to tree 2 is fine, but from tree to blob is not, even if it would save space considering their content).
3) Binary search would be hard, because of filenames in tree objects being of variable length. (Where do you look for entry 42?)

Comment: "Binary search would be hard" - pick the byte position and scan until next zero byte. But given your 1st point probably it's not that needed

Comment: The hash may contain zero bytes as well (it's 20 bytes binary, not 40 bytes hex). So it's not THAT trivial.